# Filter list of objects without using hashmap java

Tags: java, hashmap

Let's say I have a list of objects - Student(s). Each student object has various properties - roll number, class name (Not to be confused with Java class name, this is student's class name), student name etc.

The requirement is to retrieve student objects which have class name say "stack overflow". We may create a hashmap with classname (String) and it's respective student object. Is there any other solution in java which does not use hashmap? I have come across various requirements like these where generally I create an hashmap and move ahead. I'm just curious if there is a better way to solve problems like these.

Comment: Have you tried `list.stream().filter(condition).collect(toList())`?

Comment: What about  a `TreeSet` || `TreeMap` ?

Comment: This is very unclear. What exactly is "class name" in your example? how do you use `HashMap` to "filter" objects in the first place? what is the actual problem?

Comment: I am curious to see what you have currently done. The `HashMap` solution for instance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using java 8 stream api

```
Student result1 = list.stream()                        // Convert to steam
                .filter(x -> "rahul".equals(x.getName()))        // we want "rahul" only
                .findAny()                                      // If 'findAny' then return found
                .orElse(null);
```

And to collect list

```
List<Student> result1 = list.stream()                        // Convert to steam
          .filter(x -> "rahul".startsWith(x.getName()))
          .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: you should collect the filter result instead ... why only get one student ?

Comment: .collect(Collectors.toList()) use after filter